# Asynch calls versus multi-threading

Tags: .net, asynchronous, windows-services

I have a Windows Service in VB.NET that makes calls to several long running processes (regular subroutines, not web svc, remoting, or anything fancy) in sequence. I'm leary about trying to implement multithreading just because we've never done it before and this is mission crticial code. I had the thought of calling the routines asynchronously instead. I'm familiar with that and use it as part of some web services. Am I missing something? It seems like asynch calls is a "poor mans" way to avoid multithreading issues.

Answer (score 1):

Asynch calls are usually better than regular multithreading because they leverages IO COmpletion Ports thread that is more effcient in term of CPU usage.

Comment: try to look here:http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/threadpool.shtml anyway, don't mind the detail, but when the method has a begininvoke and you need to call it asynchronously, this is the way to go.

Comment: This is only true if you're doing asynchronous I/O, and the only way it's "more efficient" is that the thread can do a wait on the I/O, thereby letting some other thread have the CPU. Asynchronous calls in general aren't any more or less efficient than what we typically think of as multithreading.

Comment: @Jim Mischel aren't DB connection eventually deal with I/O on socket ?

Comment: @Felice: Yes. That doesn't change anything I said above, does it?

Comment: @Jim Doesen't using Async mehod invocation behave better in term of efficiency when we use sockets ? In that sense Asynch invocation is a "first class" way on multithreading, Isn't ?

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like asynch calls is a "poor mans" way to avoid multithreading issues.

Not necessarily. Javascript (and server variations of Javascript like Node.js) run on a single thread, but utilise lots of asynchrony so that not much time is spent waiting on a long running operation to complete. It's a way of optimising a single thread, and can be a very powerful way of programming if you've the right mindset.

If you're comfortable with asynchronous programming, then go for it! There is no need to bring in a whole lot of threads just because a task CAN be parallelised.

However, if the tasks are CPU bound, then a single thread is going to choke, and asynchrony won't help you for obvious reasons. If the task is IO, then asynchrony is probably the way to go.

Edit:

Sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant by CPU bound, is that if a particular operation is using a lot of CPU, the thread will be constantly in use, and will not be available for other tasks.

For example:

```
// task
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    for (int j = 1000000; j > 0; j--)
         sum = i + j;
```

If you needed to run the above code two times, an asynchronous model using one thread is not going to help, because a single thread will be working constantly for the whole task. If you had two threads, both can execute at exactly the same time.

```
// task
List<string> urls = GetListOfUrls();
List<string> html = new List<string>();
foreach (var url in urls) 
{
    GetUrlAsync(url, callback: (data) => html.Add(data) );
}
```

The above task is an IO task. The majority of the time in that method would be spent waiting on HTTP requests, not using CPU. If this task was synchronous, a single thread will have the same symptoms as the first. If it was asynchronous, while waiting for a HTTP request to complete, the thread is available to do more work, like kick off another download of an URL.

So, if your tasks are going to be spending a lot of time waiting for an external process, use asynchrony. Is tasks are going to be burning cpu, use multiple threads.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by CPU bound and the phrase "task is IO"? I know what IO is, but what's the context? The only IO in my routines are making the usual CRUD SQL calls. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Wow, you just learned me a ton! I really appreciate the time you spent on this great explanation. Makes alot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what multithreading issues you expect to avoid by making asynchronous calls. Asynchronous calls *are* multithreading. The only real difference is that an async call is typically used for a relatively short-lived task whereas traditional multithreading (where you  explicitly create a thread and start it running) is typically used for long-running tasks.

Either way, you still have the same concurrency issues.

You *can* use asynchronous calls for long-running tasks. In fact, the `Task` class has a constructor that lets you specify [creation options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx), including `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`.

Managing your own threads using the `Thread` class is a little bit more complicated than using something like `Task` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, but it also gives you slightly more control. Any way you do it, you have to deal with concurrency issues like race conditions and thread-safe data structures (if multiple threads are modifying a data structure). I wouldn't call asynchronous calls a "poor man's multithreading." The differences aren't that large. They're just two different ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Asynchronous does not necessarily mean multithreaded. Javascript is a prime example of that. So is the new async feature being developed for C# 5. Asynchronous CAN use multiple threads, but does not require them. Protecting against race-conditions (with locks) are not necessary with single-threaded async code.

Comment: @Josh: Granted. But the type of asynchronous calls the OP is talking about does involve multithreading.

Comment: I'm not totally convinced of that since the OP gives no code or hint to how he intends to do the work. But you also might be 100% right. I think it's still important to be aware that some async tasks can complete without another thread spinning up. cheers.